# Counting the number of files in a directory of special type in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to know if there is anyway to find the number of files exsiting in a folder with special type. For example I have a folder with 30 files with *.txt, *.doc and html extension. I want to know the number of say html file inthis directory.

**Update:** Here is what I have as a number os files in the directory. But I am not sure how I could use `glob()`. Of course, instead of `getcwd` one could give another parameter.

```
 use Cwd;
 my $dir = getcwd;
 my $count = 0;
 opendir (DIR, $dir) or die $!;
 my @dir = readdir DIR;
 my @file_list;

 if (@file_list eq glob "*.pl"){
     print "$item\n";
     $count = $count + 1;
 }

 closedir DIR; 

 $count = $count - 2;
 print "There are $count files in this directory.";
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Before writing here you should Google about it. Show us your code.

Comment: @Jens: I have added the code in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to do it without `glob()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $dir = getcwd;
my $count = 0;

opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "$0: $dir: $!\n";
while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
     # We only want files
     next unless (-f "$dir/$file");
     # Use a regular expression to find files ending in .txt
     next unless ($file =~ m/\.html$/);

     print "$file\n";
     $count = $count + 1;
 }
 closedir($dh);
 print "There are $count files in this directory.";
 exit 0;
```

Thanks a lot for the comments!!

Comment: Not bad, but I'd recommend using a lexical variable instead of a bareword directory handle: `opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "$0: $dir: $!\n"; ... readdir($dh)`

Comment: If you only want the current directory, you don't need `getcwd`; you can just open `'.'`.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I used the first suggestion. Great idea!

Comment: Good to see that you put your effort instead of asking to be spoonfed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you've got in your question is that `glob` is a bit magic. You can do this:

```
foreach my $file ( glob ("*.txt") ) {
    print $file,"\n";
}
```

and

```
while ( my $file = glob ("*.txt" )) {
    print $file,"\n";
}
```

Glob is detecting whether you're expecting a scalar (single value) return - in which case it works as an iterator - or an array (multiple scalars) - in which case it returns the whole lot.

You can make it do what you want like this:

```
my @stuff = glob ( "*.txt" );
print "There are: ", scalar @stuff," files matching the pattern\n";
print join ( "\n", @stuff );
```

Note that `readdir` works the same way - you can either slurp the whole lot doing it in a list context, or one line at a time with a scalar context:

```
opendir ( my $dirh, "some_directory");
my @stuff = readdir ( $dirh ); 

#etc.
```

Or

```
opendir ( my $dirh, "." ) or die $!;
while ( my $dir_entry = readdir ( $dirh ) ) {
    #etc.
}
```

If you do want to do readdir-and-filter you can also do it like this:

```
my @matches = grep { m/\.txt$/ } readdir ( $dirh );
```

For example (this doesn't save you any efficiency - `grep` just hides the loop. It might make it more readable - that's a matter of taste).